# "iOS app URL missing" Giving error setting up branch.io for Blogger Website

Tags: android, blogger, branch.io

I am trying to use branch.io deepview for website and setup all things according to their getting started guide.
I have only android app when i set my app in android setting and save it gives me error to add ios link too.

[image]

2nd error when i add SDK in my blogger blog after  tag it gives me that error.
[image]

Please tell me the solution.
i am trying to add this to my blog unity3diy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Branch dashboard error and since you don't have a website, why don't you just save the URL for your Google Play page in the iOS url? That way, users who click on the link on iOS will be taken to the Google Play page.

I'd also recommend doing it for the 'Default URL' at the bottom of the page.
[image: default url]

Comment: It worked :)
and also @simr solution worked too :) thnx

Answer (score 2):

As for error in blogger try wrapping javascript code in `<![CDATA[  ... ]]>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        code here...
    //]]>
</script>
```